# jTweetsAnywhere + jQuery Masonry

Tags: callback

I'm using jTweetsAnywhere to get one of my twitter lists and then apply the Masonry effect so the tweets rearrange.

The problems is, I need to add the box class so the Mansory do its magic.
How can I make jTweetsAnywhere and this classes and load Mansory so every box is rearreanged.

Tks

Answer (score 0):

All HTML from the plugin is generated by so-called 'decorators'. jTweetsAnywhere has a lot of these decorators and each one is responsible for a certain component of the whole tweet feed. Each decorator has a default implementation supplied by the plugin but can be overwritten by configuration options.

Like:

```
$('#tweets').jTweetsAnywhere({
    username: 'tbillenstein',
    count: 5,
    tweetDecorator: function(tweet, options) {
        var html = '';
        if (options.tweetProfileImagePresent)
            html += options.tweetProfileImageDecorator(tweet, options);

        if (options.tweetBodyDecorator)
            html += options.tweetBodyDecorator(tweet, options);

        html += '<div class="jta-clear">&nbsp;</div>';

        return '<li class="jta-tweet-list-item">' + html + '</li>';
    }
});
```

The code inside the user-supplied tweetDecorator is the default implementation taken from the plugin and can be adjusted to your needs, e.g. adding an additional css class to the enclosing <li> element.